# Concatenating A POST Variable To A String

Tags: javascript, php

I have a POST value (`$_POST[ 'user-name-value' ]`) that I am referencing in PHP.  I have been successful in passing it as a parameter into a database query and in other uses, such as -

```
echo $_POST[ 'user-name-value' ];
```

The following is not successful, with not even a blank alert box being displayed...

```
echo '<script>alert( ' . $_POST[ 'user-name-value' ] . ')</script>';
```

How should I go about displaying `$_POST[ 'user-name-value' ]` in an alert box?

Comment: Wrap the post value in the quotes, `echo '<script>alert("' . $_POST[ 'user-name-value' ] . '")</script>';`

Comment: Tushar, that seems obvious now that you mention it!  It works just fine now.  If you want to post that as an Answer, I will be happy to accept it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Replace -

```
echo '<script>alert( ' . $_POST[ 'user-name-value' ] . ')</script>';
```

With -

```
echo '<script>alert( "' . $_POST[ 'user-name-value' ] . '" )</script>';
```

Note the added double-quotes (").

Comment: Forgive me, but I am still fairly new to StackOverflow.  How is it not an answer?

Comment: You should add the code that has solved the problem, this should be comment on the question

Comment: Tushar, this is not only an answer, but a complete and correct one.

Comment: CollinD, I just edited this from an answer that said "Tushar's comment good", or words to that effect.

Comment: @CollinD Please see the [revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33029912/revisions)

Answer (score 0):

If a user adds a double quote in the POST variable, it will break your code, so try this:

```
echo '<script>alert("' . str_replace($_POST['user-name-value'], '"', '\"') . '");</script>';
```

This simply escapes double quotes so it doesn't end the JavaScript alert and break your code.